# @Input() value is undefined

Tags: angular, input, undefined

I've created component which takes an `@Input()` value but I always get `undefind`.
Here's my code:

parent.html

```
<added-item
      [minItemValueLength]="minItemValueLength"
      [maxItemValueLength]="maxItemValueLength"
      [listOfItems]="listOfItems"
  ></added-item>
```

children.ts

```
export class AddedItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{

  @Input() minItemValueLength: number;
  @Input() maxItemValueLength: number;
  @Input() listOfItems: string[];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.minItemValueLength)      // return 3 
    console.log(this.listOfItems)             // return undefined
  }
}
```

parent.ts

```
export class LocationsTabComponent implements OnInit {
  listOfItems: string[];
  minItemValueLength = 3;
  maxItemValueLength = 15;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.locationService.getLocations().subscribe((locations) => {
      this.getLocationsList();
      console.log(this.listOfItems)    // return Array(6)
    });
  }
  private getLocationsList() {
    this.listOfItems = this.locations.map((location: Location) => location.name);
    console.log(this.listOfItems)    // return Array(6)
  }
}
```

If I use `ngOnChanges()` in children than it at first output me:

`data undefined` and then:

`data Array(6)`

How can I get this value in `onInit`?

Would be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value isn't always `undefined` only on the time the component is created, and this is because you passed as such.

Process:

1. Parent is creating and `ngOnInit` is starting.
2. `ngOnInit` has Observable\Promise\Async method, which means we're not waiting for the response, thus the value is still undefined.
3. Child component is created and executing the `ngOnInit`. value still undefined.
4. The `Observable\Promise\Async` method is now finally finished and custom callback you created now assigned the value, and the value is passed to the child component.
   So of course child `ngOnInit` will not accept it because the component was already created.

There are couple of solutions:

1. Put `*ngIf="listOfItems"` on `added-item`.
2. Decorate Parent as `async ngOnInit`, change: `.subscribe` to `.toPromise` e.g: `await this.locationService.getLocations().toPromise...`, now parent `ngOnInit` will wait for response.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation! That's really helped! Now I understand all this process.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you assign

```
listOfItems = ...
```

in an async callback method.

If you want to detect the changes, you should implement onChanges interface and implement the corresponding hook method.

```
export class AddedItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{

    @Input() minItemValueLength: number;
    @Input() maxItemValueLength: number;
    @Input() listOfItems: string[];

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.minItemValueLength)      // return 3 
        console.log(this.listOfItems)             // return undefined
    }
    
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes.listOfItems) {
            console.log(this.listOfItems)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your subscribing to the locations, you can use [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to wait until the response is fully resolved or otherwise you have to implement `OnChanges` interface.

```
public async ngOnInit(): void {
await this.locationService.getLocations().toPromise().then((locations) => {
  this.getLocationsList();
  console.log(this.listOfItems)    // return Array(6)
});
}
private getLocationsList() {
  this.listOfItems = this.locations.map((location: Location) => location.name);
  console.log(this.listOfItems)    // return Array(6)
}
```